# Issue in passing argument to std::function for vector of functions

Tags: c++11, vector, arguments, std-function, stdbind

I'm trying to create a vector of std::function and then pass that vector to a function. I also need to pass arguments to the function objects, so I'm using std::bind. Here is the code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void execute(vector<function<void (int)>>& fs) {
    for (auto& f : fs) 
        f();
}

void func(int k) {
    cout << "In func " << k << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    vector<function<void (int)>> x;
    auto f1 = bind(func, i);
    //f1(); // this does call intended function
    x.push_back(f1);

    execute(x);
}
```

but this gives following error:

```
function_tmpl.cpp: In function ‘void execute(std::vector >&)’:
function_tmpl.cpp:14:5: error: no match for call to ‘(std::function) ()’
   f();
     ^
In file included from function_tmpl.cpp:1:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/functional:2142:11: note: candidate is:
     class function
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/functional:2434:5: note: _Res std::function::operator()(_ArgTypes ...) const [with _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {int}]
     function::
     ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/functional:2434:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

If I call f() inside main(), that works fine, which means that the function has bound with the arguments, but it's not working when passed to another function as argument

Comment: `function<void (int)>` only accepts functions that take an `int`. Calling `f()` is missing the `int`. Either change it to `function<void()>` or use `f(0)`.

Comment: @nwp, will std::bind not bind the arguments to the function object?

Comment: It does, but `function<void (int)>` still requires an `int`. After you bound the `int` to the function the bound function does not require an `int` anymore, so it now has the signature `function<void()>`.

Comment: `@nwp` so how can I pass arguments in this case? Changing it to `function<void()>` doesn't allow to pass the bounded function, and `f(0)` won't serve the purpose?

Comment: You pass arguments when you bind the `int` to the function. If you don't know the argument the function should have when you bind it you should not bind it, go back to `function<void(int)>` and also pass a `vector<int>` for the parameters to `execute` and do something like `fs[i](arguments[i])`.

Comment: `@nwp` I know the argument the function should have when I bind it i.e. int.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a vector of void functions with a single int argument: `vector<function<void (int)>>`, but you are actually pushing `void(void)` functions. All you need to do is to change the element type of the vector to `vector<function<void (void)>>`. Bind works roughly like this:

given:

```
void f1(int i) { printf("%d", i); }
```

`bind(f1, 1)` returns a new function `f2`:

```
void f2() 
{
    f1(1);
}
```

and since you are pushing `f2`, the vector should store `void(void)` functions.

Comment: `@perreal` I'm not pushing `void(void)` functions. The function is bounded to int argument: `auto f1 = bind(func, i);`

Comment: correct, but the element type of the vector is not correct since you are pushing bound functions that do not take arguments. So the functions you are pushing have different type than original functions.

Comment: `@perreal` may be I'm missing something, but the bound function i.e. func, takes an argument?

Comment: `@perreal` +1 for bind explanation in edit. That brings clarity. The good thing is that I'm able to push functors and lambda functions also into the same vector.

Answer (score 1):

After binding, the type of function has become to `void()`. So change the type of `vector` to `vector<function<void ()>>`, you'll get it.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void execute(vector<function<void ()>>& fs) {
    for (auto& f : fs) 
        f();
}

void func(int k) {
    cout << "In func " << k << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    vector<function<void ()>> x;
    auto f1 = bind(func, i);
    x.push_back(f1);

    execute(x);
}
```

result:

```
In func 1
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/GWG39093)

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `std::bind` is unspecified. Hence you cannot expect `std::bind` to return a variable of same type as `std::function<void(int)>`. Use `decltype` and templates to resolve.

[Here is an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68869aa45b28d537)

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void execute(vector<T>& fs) {
    for (auto& f : fs) 
        f();
}

void func(int k) {
    cout << "In func " << k << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    auto f1 = bind(func, i);
    vector<decltype(f1)> x; //deduce type of f1
    x.push_back(f1);
    execute(x);
}
```

Comment: Q1 This solves one problem of passing argument. But, I just don't want to push plain function in vector, I want to push functor and lambda function also. So I can't use decltype to get the type. How to fix this?

Comment: See @songyuanyao's answer for how you can achieve that with templates.
Example : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df682223032a9ec9

Comment: Or you wanted to write 'without' templates?

Comment: Yes without templates.

Answer (score 0):

f is of type 
    function<void (int)>& 
so the compiler expects you to provide a parameter, like this:
    f(1)

Comment: `@ZunTzu`, will std::bind not bind the arguments to the function object?

Comment: This is true for f1, but not for f, which is statically defined as taking one parameter.